# Not the right method for css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

im trying to reproduce this piece of website: [image]

here's mine now and im gonna explain why im struggling

[image]

Im struggling with the way to do it, i can move the description close to the logo playing with margin but when i move the size of my screen everything gonna be messed up and i feel like its not the right move to do. Im trying to use flex-boxe but i feel like i messed up the whole part and i should restart again i show you the big picture now:

[image]

And here's the whole code for all that part

```
<div class="container-services_display">        
        <img src="images/main-feature.png">

                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="icon_placement">
                        <i class="material-icons">android</i>
                    </div>
                        <div class="icon_placement2 ball_design"> 
                            <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                </div> 
                        <div class="description-services_right">
                            <h2> UX design </h2>
                            <p>Coucou les amis je suis entrain de faire un site chiant</p>
                            <p>Coucou les amis je suis entrain de faire un site chiant</p>
                        </div>                       
    </div>
```

css:

```
.container-services_display

{
    margin-top: 110px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}


.ball_display

{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


.ball_design

{
    color: rgb(82, 162, 201);
    font-size: 14px;
}


.circle 

{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 75px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(237, 238, 239, 1);
    border-opacity: 0.5;
}


.icon_placement

{
    position: relative;
    left: 24px;
    top: 22px;
    color: rgb(96, 174, 209);
}


.icon_placement2

{
    position: relative;
    left: 68px;
}
```

So basically its wrapper on a container, im trying to display it on the horizontal with flex and they space it but i feel like i miss a part of this, what i would do is making another div for the logo + description and displaying again with flex but it seemed like its not working, i just need some hint and sorry i only got less than 20 hours of css =D

Comment: Could u provide your `html` ?

Comment: I feel like bootstrap would be easier to achieve the wanted result. Could you post your html aswell?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the answers

Comment: I just post the html

Comment: `Coucou les amis je suis en train de faire un site chiant` XD

Answer (score 0):

since you are using css flex then you need to add `flex: 1` and little margin if you want it for spacing

```
.description-services_right {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62w74n6r/3/)

**here is bootstrap version if you want to go with bootstrap**

```css
.side-pic{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
.mtop{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.side-pic-holder{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-2 side-pic-holder">
    
      <img class="side-pic" src="http://random-ize.com/lorem-ipsum-generators/lorem-ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg" />
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <h4>some title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row mtop">

  
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <h4>some title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 side-pic-holder">
    
      <img class="side-pic" src="http://random-ize.com/lorem-ipsum-generators/lorem-ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg" />
    
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

make sure you view it as `full screen`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is when i move the screen everything is  messed up so im just wondering am i supposed to code on a single size screen and then taking care of the jquery after ?

Answer (score 0):

### Media Query

In Order to have a clean and responsive Website you will need to use some Media Queries. If your are new to Media Query, [check it out here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp).

> In the Media Query you can define your CSS Classes and stylings like
>   usually, the only difference is it will be only applied if the
>   condition is true. For Example: If the screen-width is less than 768px

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
  .description-services_right{
  width: 100%;
  }
}
```

### Bootstrap

There is an other Way, probably the easier and quicker one, using Bootstrap 3/4, if your never heard of Bootstrap you can [read their Doc here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).

> Bootstrap lets you create Quickly Responsive Websites just by adding
>   premade classes to your HTML Elements.

Bootstrap biggest Advantage is its Grid System, before i get into too much explanations you should check it out if you are interested.

I created two Pens where i made your Code Responsive, i kept all the HTML Elements but deleted all unnecessary CSS.

You can even compare the Bootstrap and Non-Bootstrap Version i made to see how much Coding you can avoid.

[Pen without Bootstrap](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/NYayxx)

[Pen with bootstrap](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/aYLqyj)

[And here a Demo how Bootstraps Grid System works](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/EEwQOO)